# Determining Scale when using both Sum and case statements. Strange result

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqldatatypes

trying to understand why the end result of my query is return decimal(18,2) instead of decimal(18,3).

i know that sum will return decimal(38, s), and i know there is some data type precedence in terms of what results you return from a case statement, but i cant find any literature on the changing of scale within case statements when both returns decimal with different scale

why does the below query return decimal(38,2) instead of decimal(38,3)?

Note that i know how to fix this query, i'm more so interested as to why its not working in its current form.

Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE supportContacts 
    (
PolicyNumber char(1),
LoadingRate decimal(18,2),
LoadingRate2 decimal(18,3)
    );

INSERT INTO supportContacts
(PolicyNumber, LoadingRate,LoadingRate2)
VALUES
('A', '15.52', '15.523'),
('B', '18.54', '15.525'),
('C', '1.25', '15.552');

select PolicyNumber
     , case when PolicyNumber = 'A' then sum(loadingrate2)
            else sum(LoadingRate)
            end

     from #supportContacts
group by PolicyNumber
```

SQL Fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4ecd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> within case statements when both returns decimal with different scale

Not possible. A [`CASE` *expression*](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) computes a value. The data type of the value it produces is determined via the [data type precedence rules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), but the values it can return have to all be converted to a *single* data type.

As to why it selects `(38,2)` over `(38,3)`, well, if it doesn't have enough bits available, it will always sacrifice scale over precision. See e.g. [Precision, Scale and Length](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx):

> - The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the corresponding scale is reduced to prevent the integral part of a result from being truncated.

---

The datatypes produced by the `SUM()` calls are `decimal(38,2)` and `decimal(38,3)`. We can then use the same rules as included in the above link to work out what `CASE` is going to do to determine its result type. The rules to follow are the ones specified for the `e1 { UNION | EXCEPT | INTERSECT } e2` operation.

The result precision is given as `max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2)` - which is `max(2,3) + max(38-2, 38-3)` - which is `3 + 36` which is `39`. As stated, since the maximum precision is `38`, we have to reduce the resultant scale.

Comment: when would it occur that it doesnt have enough bits available?

Comment: @user1517263 - it think it has values that can fill a `(38,2)` and a `(38,3)`. If storage size was no issue, it would want to create a `(39,3)` and then all possible values could be stored. But such is not the case, the maximum precision is `38`. So, as in the quote, it chooses to truncate scale so that any possible `(38,2)` value can be stored without having to truncate the integral portion.

Comment: in the example provided, the max any sum could be is just decimal(2,3), so i dont think its reaching the max precision in this case.

Comment: @user1517263 - the declared types of your columns are `(18,2)` and `(18,3)` so you'll never get a `(2,3)` - it's the declared types that matter, not how small a type you may be able to find that can contain a *value* without loss of important data. And the declared return type of `SUM()` is always `(38,s)` where `s` matches the scale of the declared input type for the `SUM()`.

Comment: yes forgot about the returned sum datatype. still though, from the example giving above, there shouldn't be any reason why it would go about precision 38, should there?

Comment: @user1517263 - from the [Precision, Scale and Length](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) link, the equivalent of determining the result type of a `CASE` expression with mismatched parameters is the same as the `e1 { UNION | EXCEPT | INTERSECT } e2` operation - I show how that calculates out as a precision of 39, and then the footnote applies to get back to a precision of 38.

Comment: i see your edit now, and that makes sense. thanks for the help, that was wrecking my head.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly cast to decimal(18,3) when using case statement like --

```
select PolicyNumber , 
    case when PolicyNumber = 'A' then 
    CAST(sum(loadingrate2) AS DECIMAL(18,3))
    else CAST(sum(loadingrate) AS DECIMAL(18,3))
    end  AS LoadingRate
    from supportContacts
    group by PolicyNumber
```

Comment: i understand how to get it working, im more curious as to why the above doesnt work. i could also just put the sum outside the case statement too.